# Android DialogFragment null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with a `DialogFragment`.

I've removed all my code and made the `DialogFragment` as simple as possible and it actually works when called from the `MainActivity`.
This is the code:

The `DatePickerFragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container, false);
       getDialog().setTitle("Simple Dialog");
       return rootView;
   }
}
```

The call from the `MainActivity`:

```
public void showDialog
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    DatePickerFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment ();
    dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
}
```

But, if I call `showDialog` from a class `ActivityStarter` that has a reference to `MainActivity`, this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2353)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1812)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1359)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1623)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm really stuck and cannot find a solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When is the ActivityStarter created ? Are you returning null in any of the createView's in any of the classes ?

Comment: MainActivity -> onCreate -> ActivityStarter activityStarter = new ActivityStarter(); All the rest works from `activityStarter`, the only problem I have is in the call to `showDialog`. I'm not returning null.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are calling the DialogFragment from class ActivityStarter?

Comment: ActivityStarter its a instance of MainActivity, bur you never pass the "context" to ActivityStarter, i think is for this you give that error

Comment: @Gogeta It's now simplified to:

    public void startActivity(int RequestCode)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (RequestCode)
            {
               ...
             
               case Constants.REQUEST_DATE_PICKER:
               {
                  m_a.showDialog();
                  break;
               }

Comment: @brayancamilovillateleon: I thought about it and tried with an interface passed from MainActivity to ActivityStarter but it doesn't solve.

Comment: What is that `ListView` mentioned in the stack trace? Does that `ListView` have a non-null adapter?

Comment: try send FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); not the context maybe thats solve the problem

Comment: @dhke: this is the problem, I don't have any `ListView` as I removed all my code and made it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the reason. Thanks to all but the problem is not caused by the `DialogFragment` that has nothing to do with this.

The crash was caused by the method call just before the `DialogFragment.show()` and that was confusing me.

I explain even though this will never help anyone as it's a problem just of my code:

I'm opening the `DatePickerFragment` exactly after the user has inserted his name.
Before, the name was inside a child of an `ExpandableListView`'s group so I was calling `expandGroup()` to show it.
Actually the name is not changable anymore so it's not in a child but in a locked group of the `ExpandableListView`.
I just forgot to remove the call to `expandGroup()` that, with no children, was causing the crash (that's why the ListView problem).

Thanks again, posting here helped me anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityStarter activityStarter = new ActivityStarter(this);
}

public onSomeEvent() {
    activityStarter.showDialog();
}
```

In ActivityStarter:

```
Context context;

ActivityStarter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void showDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = context.getFragmentManager();
    DatePickerFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment ();
    dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
}
```

Comment: As someone in the OP comments suggested, ActivityStarter does not have the correct context to call getFragmentManager. Unless OP sets this explicitly somewhere not mentioned, an error should result.

Comment: `getFragmentManager` is not a method of `Context`